# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable when parsing user input

Tags: python, input

## Objective: input list [2,7] receive output [2,7,3]

```
print('when asked for first two numbers type 27')
response = int(input('first two numbers of the list?  '))
start_list = list(response)
print('first two numbers of the list are', start_list)
if start_list[0] < start_list[1]:
    new = start_list[0] + 1
    start_list.insert(2, new)
print('first algo run gives', start_list)
```

## Output: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

## Is there a better way?

Comment: Say the user gives you a `1`. What do you expect expect `start_list = list(response)` will do? If you're expecting the user to supply more than 1 numbers, you'll need to handle that before parsing the strings as numbers.

Comment: maybe try `response = list(input('first two numbers of the list?  '))` then
`start_list = map(int, response)`

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you want the user to input two integers separated by spaces. This is definitely not how you'd do it. To begin with, applying `int` on an input looking like `"123 456"` isn't the right way to go about it. You'd need `str.split`, followed by a conversion of each element to an integer. The common idiom for this is:

```
x, y = map(int, input('Enter two numbers: ').split())
Enter two numbers: 123 456

print(x, y)
(123, 456)
```

After this, you might as well put your numbers in a list:

```
start_list = [x, y]
```

Or, if you don't want to unpack the `map` result, you may use:

```
start_list = list(map(int, input('Enter two numbers: ').split()))
```

Omit the `list` bit if you're using python2.

---

Do note here that unpacking is not a good idea if the user enters anything more or less than two numbers separated by spaces. In such events you're better off not unpacking the result to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to accept 2 numbers you might want to use raw_input

```
response = raw_input('first two numbers of the list?  ') # this will give you a string like '1 2'
```

Then you want to convert that to a list of ints

```
start_list = [int(x) for x in response.split()]
```

then your the rest of your code should work fine

Answer (score 0):

You can do some modification how you make the list

```
print('when asked for first two numbers type 27')
response = input('first two numbers of the list?  ')
start_list = list(map(int, response.split()))
print('first two numbers of the list are', start_list)
if start_list[0] < start_list[1]:
    new = start_list[0] + 1
    start_list.insert(2, new)
print('first algo run gives', start_list)
```

Output

```
when asked for first two numbers type 27
first two numbers of the list?  1 10
first two numbers of the list are [1, 10]
first algo run gives [1, 10, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using coldspeed's suggestion, and recognizing that `split()` returns a list of strings...

And then remembering to convert the string back to an int, this seems to solve the problem on my system:

```
start_list = list(input('Enter two numbers: ').split())
print('first two numbers of the list are', start_list)
if start_list[0] < start_list[1]:
    new = int(start_list[0]) + 1  # need to convert first string to an int with a call to int()
    start_list.insert(2, new)
print('first algo run gives', start_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are leaning Python.  Here is my suggestion:

The best way to get the user to enter exactly two numbers is to prompt him twice.  The function `input` returns a string, which you can convert to an int (as you have done).

```
print('when asked for first two numbers enter 2 and 7')
response1 = int(input('Enter the first integer'))
response2 = int(input('Enter the second integer'))
```

Make these two values into a list.  The easiest way to do this is using the `[...]` syntax:

```
start_list = [response1, response2]
print('first two numbers of the list are', start_list)
```

Now append your third element.

```
if start_list[0] < start_list[1]:
    new_value = start_list[0] + 1  # don't use the name new
    start_list.append(new_value)  # append always adds it at the end
print('first algo run gives', start_list)  # what's an algo?
```

The name `new` is not a good name for a variable, since it has a special meaning.

Use `append` rather than `insert` if you know you want the value to go at the end of the list.

Answer (score -1):

I think the error is with this code:

```
start_list = list(response)
```

you should put your response between [] like:

```
start_list = list([response])
```

Comment: This may solve the one error, but I can't imagine that this will actually help the OP. This will probably just cause another error later down.